# CSS Floating Images with Text Inside DIV

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs that contain an image and some text. When I try floating the image to the left using float:left; the other elements have weird formatings . Below is my code and an image of what happens:

**HTML**

```
<div class="skills">
  <h2>My Skills.</h2>
  <div class="skill-row">
    <img class="muscle"src="images/strong.png" alt="muscle">

    <h3>Physical Capabilities</h3>
    <p>I am physically fit, tall and lean from years of playing outside.</p>

  </div>
  <div class="skill-row">
    <img class="brain" src="images/brainstorm.png" alt="brain">

    <h3>Intelligence</h3>
    <p>I am able to perform mathematical calculations with ease, and understand advanced concepts.</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.skill-row{ 
width: 50%;
margin: 100px auto 100px auto; 
text-align: left; line-height: 2;
}

.muscle {
 width: 25%;
float: left;
}

.brain {
 width: 25%;
float: left;
}
```

[Image of Site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6GPr.png)

What can I do to float the image to the left while keeping the rest of my webpage in tact?

Comment: Using the code you have given I cannot get the image that you have given. In my test the divs are one above the other, properly aligned. Please could you put up a working snippet (with imgs) that shows the problem when we run it?

Answer (score 0):

Float affects other inline elements. You can clear the float on the other elements, in this case:

```
h3 {
 clear: left;
}
```

More about css 'clear'
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp

```css
.skill-row{ 
width: 50%;
margin: 100px auto 100px auto; 
text-align: left; line-height: 2;
}

.muscle {
 width: 25%;
float: left;
}

.brain {
 width: 25%;
float: left;
}

h3 {
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="skills">
  <h2>My Skills.</h2>
  <div class="skill-row">
    <img class="muscle"src="images/strong.png" alt="muscle">

    <h3>Physical Capabilities</h3>
    <p>I am physically fit, tall and lean from years of playing outside.</p>

  </div>
  <div class="skill-row">
    <img class="brain" src="images/brainstorm.png" alt="brain">

    <h3>Intelligence</h3>
    <p>I am able to perform mathematical calculations with ease, and understand advanced concepts.</p>

  </div>
</div>
```